# How do I iterate over collection in aurelia templates

Tags: javascript, templates, handlebars.js, aurelia

I am currently trying to replicate the following handlebars syntax with aurelia

```html
<td><span>{{#each person.colours}}{{name}}{{#unless @last}}, {{/unless}}{{/each}}</span></td>
```

I know there is the `repeat.for` attribute for html elements but I don't want to repeat any element in this case.

So given a object of the folowing shape:

```js
{
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: "Doe",
    colours: [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: "Red"
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            name: "Green"
        }
    ]
}
```

should generate the following output:

```html
<td><span>Red, Green</span></td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<require from="./colour-names-value-converter"></require>

<td><span>${person.colours | colourNames}</span></td>
```

**colour-names-value-converter.js**

```js
export class ColourNamesValueConverter {
  toView(colours) {
    return colour.map(c => c.name).join(', ');
  }
}
```

Comment: That wouldn't work because colours is an array of colour object not string.

Comment: the map in the converter translates the object array to a string- maybe you're commenting on an old version of this answer before I noticed the object array?

Comment: I believe I was commenting on an old edit of the answer Yes,  I'll try this probably tomorrow and if it works I'll mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
get colours() {
  return this.item.colours.map(colour => colour.name).join(', ');
}

<td><span>${colours}</span></td>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, I had already thought of that and it would work, but I was hoping `aurelia`  might cater for this without creating a function on the viewmodel.

Comment: I see... Usually, I prefer to not put "code" in the view. However, I'll try to find a solution that does not use a function.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my temporary solution which works and follows the same idea as [Fabio Luz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1148153/fabio-luz) was hinting at, so on the view model provide the method compute the result.

```typescript
colours(person: IPerson) {
  return person.colours.map(colour => colour.name).join(', ');
}
```

then in the template pass the person into the method:

```
<td><span>${colours(person)}</span></td>
```

results in

```html
<td><span>Red, Green</span></td>
```

If someone comes up with an answer that allows this to be done in the template like handlebars does I will mark that as the answer.